# could anyone can explain what this means

Tags: scala

```
scala> val sample ="1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED"
sample: String = 1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED

scala> sample.split(",")(1).split(" ")
res15: Array[String] = Array(2013-07-25, 00:00:00.0)

scala> sample.split(",")(1).split(" ")(0).split("-").mkString("").toInt
res16: Int = 20130725

scala> sample.split(",")(1)split(" ")
res17: Array[String] = Array(2013-07-25, 00:00:00.0)

scala> sample.split(",")(1)split(" ")(0).split("-").mkString("").toInt
<console>:28: error: value split is not a member of Char
              sample.split(",")(1)split(" ")(0).split("-").mkString("").toInt
                                            ^
```

here the missed dot works only works on one case…
I did a typo and I’ve noticed that but I am curious to know if there is an explanation to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that without the dot, methods are being applied to the wrong elements.

```
sample.split(",")(1)split(" ")
     // missing dot ^  becomes the same as
sample.split(",")(1) split " "
```

Everything that follows is applied, via `apply()`, to the `String` argument being passed to `split()`.

```
sample.split(",")(1) split " "(0) //the 0 index is the 1st Char of the String

sample.split(",")(1) split " "(0).split("-") //can't split a Char
```

Comment: I deleted the part that criticized my answer. :) thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you omit dot in `sample.split(",")(1)split(" ")(0)`, this is actual equal to `sample.split(",")(1) split (" ")(0)`, Since when you omit dot, you also can **omit parenthesis**.

and for `(" ")(0)` there is a **implicit conversion** in there, convert the `String` to `StringOps`: [implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html#augmentString(x:String):scala.collection.immutable.StringOps), it can be a **Char Collection**: `IndexedSeqOptimized[Char, Repr]`, so `(" ")(0)` will return `" "` first character  from this **String Collection**.

So `sample.split(",")(1) split (" ")(0)` also it's equal to `sample.split(",")(1) split " "`, since the above **implicit conversion**. so `sample.split(",")(1) split " "` type still is `Array[String]` not `String` type. of course `split` will not work in `Array` type.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot a period after `(1)`

`sample.split(",")(1).split(" ")(0).split("-").mkString("").toInt`

Comment: hey i know that i did mention it below but i wanted to know the explanation of that

Comment: ah. Read it too fast.